# HBase installation with Hadoop YARN

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to install HBase v0.98.6 on ubuntu.  I already have Hadoop YARN running on the OS.  Should I stop the existing Hadoop processes and rely solely on HBase or configure HBase with existing YARN setup?  I can share more information if needed.  I am trying to run HBase first on pseudo-distributed and then in distributed mode.

To be clear - I am asking whether I need Hadoop YARN running before I install HBase (in a distributed manner - not on a single computer).  If not, and I still have Hadoop YARN on those computers, will it cause any issues for HBase to run on those servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit confusing. But the point is HBase & YARN are not dependent on each other.

You can very well stop the YARN service and use HBase. The only services HBase will use from your existing cluster are HDFS & Zookeeper.

Some places people use MapReduce to aggregate data for HBase tables. And in that case both can coexist.

If your use case is real time data access/update with high throughput then i would recommend not running  YARN along with HBase.

Hope this was what you were looking for :)

Comment: thanks - it was helpful.  I was also wondering if it could potentially cause issues with ports (if common) etc but I guess not.

Comment: Not unless you change the default ports.

Comment: thanks - so in short, if I just need to install HBase on HDFS, I do not need to setup Hadoop?  and if I do, it does not create any clashes

Comment: I am eventually trying to install HBase in a cluster and not just on a single node

Comment: Hadoop is composed of HDFS, MapReduce or YARN (10 or 2.0) So you will have to install some components of Hadoop.

Comment: so will I have to install Hadoop (YARN) before I install HBase or will HBase packaged with HDFS/Zookeeper?

Comment: Install Hadoop 2.0 which will install HDFS. The install Zookeeper. Then install HBase. Again depends on ditribution. I use Cloudera which automates the whole process.

Comment: There is [Hoya](https://github.com/hortonworks/hoya), a project from Hortonworks to run HBase on top of YARN. Not production ready just yet though.